# How to processing "tr" command inside all files in a folder?

Tags: unix, tr

I can do this like for one file:

```
tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" < some_file
```

---

But, how to processing `tr` to all files in a folder recursive?

```
tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" < /some_folder
```

or

```
tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" < *
```

---

It gives me an error like:

```
tr: read error: Is a directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` and `xargs` to pipe the file contents into `tr` like so:

```
find some_folder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat|tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n"
```